# access subcollection in firebase firestore v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access the firebase firestore documents inside subcollection (messages):

```
user > user.uid > messages > docRef.id > date: Date.now()
                                         text: userText
                  userEmail: user.email
                  userName: display.name
```

I used the following:

```
const snapRef2 = collection(db, "users/" + user.uid + "/messages")
onSnapshot(snapRef2, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
    })
})
```

But this method works only when user.uid is a string like: `const snapRef2 = collection(db, "users/randomstring/messages")`

How do I access the documents inside messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your answer works if you want to retrieve the messages for a specific user, identified by `user.uid`.

If you want to get the messages for all users, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Such a query reads from all collections with a specific name, like `messages`:

```
const snapRef2 = collectionGroup(db, "messages")
...
```

The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: This works without the "/messages". It should be "messages". But it works

Answer (score 3):

```
const snapRef2 = collection(db, `users/${user.uid}/messages`)
```

Make sure to use back ticks instead of quotation marks